# Why do I have a worse performance of redis from ruby?

Tags: ruby, redis

I've installed redis on a local virtual machine and run this code on my host. So I try to insert rows from a csv file to redis db. The CSV file includes 11000 rows and needs 20 seconds and I don't know why.

My code is:

```
require "redis"
require "csv"

CSV_FILE = "./data/SB_HI_OESL.CSV"
$redis = Redis.new(:host => "127.0.0.1", :port => 6379, :db => 0)

def insert_parent_child(parent, child)
  start = Time.now
  $redis.set("H:P:%s:%s" % [child[0], child[1]], "%s:%s" % [parent[4], parent[5]])
  finish = Time.now
  p (finish-start).inspect
end

CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, { :col_sep => ';' }) do |row|

  if $. != 1
    insert_parent_child(row[-2..-1], row[0..1])
  end
end
```

Output is:
"0.006501"
"0.003001"
"0.0005"
"0.011502"
"0.012002"
"0.004001"
"0.010502"
"0.011002"

I changed it to:

```
start = Time.now
$redis.pipelined {
  CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, { :col_sep => ';' }) do |row|
    if $. != 1
      insert_parent_child(row[-2..-1], row[0..1])
    end
  end
}

finish = Time.now
p (finish-start).inspect
```

Now output is "0.7315"

Comment: If you need simply insertions, strongly recommend you using of PIPELINE inserts (http://redis.io/topics/pipelining). The difference will be very significant.

Comment: You're running this synchronously ...

Comment: How can I do it asynchronously?